# Manager introduced me to new joinees in unprofessional way - Updated

Tags: software-industry, manager, unprofessional-behavior

I work for a software product in a software company. It has been more than three months that I joined this company.

In past few release cycles I have struggled due to a learning curve of the product and business domain etc. My manager does not have good feedback about me.

Today a few interns/junior developers have joined the organization and it was an introduction session. My manager introduced me saying,

> "He is [My Name], having experience of 7+ years. He keeps working on
>   problems. Problems do not come to him, he actually goes to the
>   problems. Overall a good guy and everybody in my team is."

As a human being I am feeling offended and thinking even if he has any negative feedback about me, he may have discussed this in person with me.

Isn't this a bit unprofessional?

Can you please suggest, should I ignore this and move on or should I report this to the Upper management level to the manager?

**AFTER SEEING THE GENERAL PERCEPTION IN COMMENTS (POSITIVE)**

I was just surprised the way he introduced very first time with the limitation (maybe a quality as others are evaluating it). Is it normal?  Can be my own perception which is negative?

Comments and answers are pushing me to think in a positive way, which is good thing but I need a little bit more time to be convinced.

Comment: Why do you think this is negative feedback? Can you explain what you find here to be negative?

Comment: That sounds like your manager was complimenting you - you go after problems and tackle them, rather than waiting around for problems to come to you.

Comment: "Problems do not come to him, he actually goes to the problems" => "He is proactive, not reactive"

Comment: @Oded i am feeling it offending because i struggled a bit here and there with the things and then this introduction took place.

Comment: @Prinz and oded really this can be the positive outlook towards the situation. this is why i asked for the suggestions

Comment: OK, but the two things don't seem related to each other. You have some difficulties, OK (everyone has them on a new job). The introduction is something different - and it is likely you are reading something negative in it that wasn't intended. Again - what do you see in that introduction as negative?

Comment: @Oded it projects me as a senior developer who always struggle and stuck in problems

Comment: `My manager have not so good feedback about me` are you sure this actually is or is it a kind of 'feeling / heard that from others' ? Did you discuss this with him 1:1 ? is that why you think it was negative comment ?

Comment: How so? It says you **go after** problems, meaning you seek them out in order to solve them. That's a good thing.

Comment: @Devjosh, I see nothing negative here.  He even said "overall a good guy" and then linked you to the team "everybody on my team is." - that means he  is saying you are just like his team - good.

Comment: Updated the question and will think over it once again. i thank everyone here to be so positive about me including my manager :)

Comment: I actually read this as positive - that is the problems are not your own but you seek out others to solve, that's great!

Comment: Your Boss introduction was very positive, I think : The way I read it it means "this persons doesn't wait for problems to occur, he seeks them (implicitely meaning: you are trying to find (and fix) problems before they occur)"  ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the comments are showing here, maybe you've misinterpreted what your manager actually meant.  You might feel that maybe it's rude to inquire, but honestly the only way to know for certain what your manager meant by his expression would be for you to put your vexation aside and just ***ask*** him.

If you were to run to upper management without truly understanding what was expressed, you'd end up looking like an ass.  Not worth it.  Ask!

Comment: seems to be the good option to go for. i will try to go 1:1

Comment: @Devjosh I agree with this answer; when I read through the quote, my interpretation was "This is someone who is really good at *solving* problems that are assigned to him, and he seeks out things that he can improve"; When you heard this, did you think it meant that he was saying you had a lot of personal problems that needed work?

Comment: @schizoid04 yes, at first but later i concluded that i was taking it in wrong direction.

Answer (score 5):

Here at the Workplace, we have a rule: "assume good intentions".  I think applying it to your manager would be good in this case.

Honestly, I am having a hard time seeing any insult in this.  It looks more like he was making a joke in the style of "Chuck Norris Facts"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Norris_facts

later, he says that you are a good guy.

where is the insult/ lack of professionalism?

Answer (score 3):

> He keeps working on problems. Problems do not come to him, he actually goes to the problems.

He is saying that you are proactive. You deal with problems before they start affecting you. If you are become idle, you search for a problem to fix. I would say that's a positive comment. I would certainly take it as a positive comment.

Taken in the context of the full comment, it looks to me like a very positive comment.

Yes, he should have said in a clearer way. He was probably trying to impress the interns. It looks like he was exaggerating a bit. In other words, he was trying to make you look as a very hard working men in front of the interns. As far as I know, he was trying to paint you in a very good light.

I have seen a couple of similar presentations. They were made half as a joke. However, the meaning was positive. We were being told to respect that worker as a hard-working colleague. The overall tone was very familiar and the manager was exaggerating a bit as a joke.

Comment: I interpret it exactly the same way.